# Create different fragment types by one function

Tags: java, android

I need a function in my Activity, that sets fragment to my ViewGroup (FrameLayout in this case). Of course, I can use such construction:

```
public void setFragment(Fragment fragment){
    FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
    //etc
}
```

But with this solution I need to create `fragment` somewhere else, not in my function. So, if class `MyFragment` extends `Fragment`, I need something like this:

```
setFragment(MyFragment);
```

Is it possible? **Can I pass class as a parameter of function and then create instance of it**

And if it's not - is it a bad idea to create fragment behind the function? Like

```
MyFragment my=new MyFragment();
setFragment(my);
```

Comment: why do you have to create the fragment somewhere else? why cant you create it in the function?

Comment: For example, I have two different fragments with (with two different layouts respectively). What should I pass to function as a parameter?

Comment: are the 2 fragments using the same Framelayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two fragments are using the same layout then you can just do something like this

```
public void setFragment(){

Fragment newFragment;

if(displayFragOne){
newFragment = new MyFragment();
}else if(displayFragTwo){
newFragment = new OtherFragment();
} 

FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(r.id.the_id_of_layout,fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

the fragment paramater is passed in from where you initialized it usually in `onCreate()`

if you need the fragments to display at the same time then you need another `FrameLayout` to replace.

hopefully that answered your question, if not let me know

**EDIT 2:**

oh I see now you want to pass a class, sorry. As far as I know you cant do that, passing in an already initialized fragment would be a a better solution like I had before my first edit

Comment: Thanks ) But I know how to replace fragment. My question is "how to not create fragment outside of function". And it maybe not only MyFragment, but something else, that extends Fragment.

Comment: I guess you could then set up some sort of conditional boolean in the function based on when you want the fragment to be shown but I really couldnt say without looking at more code. I edited code above

Comment: ahh sorry i see now, I do not believe you can do that, passing in a fragment would be a better solution

Comment: But note: 1) in your answer your function doesn't have any params, 2) it's better to use `instance of` than boolean, int etc.